# Simple Code issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

I have a very small LAMP Ubuntu Server, and I'm .NET programmer, however. I want to create a very small PHP page that count how many people saw a specific page e.g.

http://myip/apache/page.php?name=NAME&id=X
where name is a string and id is an integer.
If this URL for example has been requested twice or more, I want to increment it just like 'a like button on Facebook'. and also, how can I create the tables in mysql database, and how can I create the new ID, but if the ID exist, then just update it by increment it by 1; +1.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to have a look at the tour on how to post a question on SO. This is [the link](http://stackoverflw/tour)

Comment: it looks that you are asking how to do a website. You can understand that there is no technical difference between save a counter and save whatever else. Try to start with w3c school http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Yeah, I really want to learn it, but the problem is I'm doing this ONLY to analyze what clients are interested in more. and I want that asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to keep the count persistent on your server. You can do that 2 ways: 1) using a file to keep the count, or 2) use a database. Depending on how you installed LAMP, you should have phpMyAdmin which will help you create your database.

If you don't have phpMyAdmin you can install it like this: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` ([details here](http://geneticcoder.blogspot.com/2014/10/how-to-set-up-apache-mysql-and-php-on.html)) then it will be available from `localhost/phpmyadmin`

MySQL has something called "auto-increment" when you create a table, set the first column to integer, set it as the primary key, then check the box for "AI" or "auto-increment" this will handle your incrementing IDs.

You'll have to read about [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to get the count from the database in PHP.

### Edit

Here's some pseudo-code that should get you started. Just copy this code into a file on your server and run it, then follow the instructions it gives you to get it set up.

```
<?php

// we will put this variable in the document for the visitor to see...
$MESSAGE = "";

// Initialize the $visitor number variable as 0, we'll change this later if there are more visitors.
$visitor_number = 0;

// The filename of the file we'll use to track our visitors count
$FILENAME = "count.txt";

// get the full path based on the relative path of the current file
$FILEPATH = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/".$FILENAME;

// check if the file exists first
if(!file_exists($FILEPATH)){
    $MESSAGE = "<b>The required file does not exist yet!</b><br> Copy and paste the following code into the command line to create it:<br><pre>sudo touch $FILEPATH</pre>";
}

// check if the file is writable
else if(!is_writable($FILEPATH) || !is_readable($FILEPATH)){
    $MESSAGE = "<b>PHP cannot write to or read from this file yet!</b><br> Copy and paste the following code into the command line to fix it: (Note: this is a bad idea on a live server, this is just a demo.)<br><pre>sudo chmod 777 $FILEPATH</pre>";
}

// if everything else works, let's get the count from the file and then update the file with the new count
else{

    // get the contents of the file
    $count = file_get_contents($FILEPATH);

    // if there is already a count, we addd one to it so as to count the current visitor
    if(!empty($count)) $count = $count+1;

    // otherwise the count starts at zero
    else $count = 1;

    // update the current count file
    // open the file for writing
    $fh = fopen($FILEPATH,"w+");

    // write the new count
    fwrite($fh, $count);

    // close the file 
    fclose($fh);

    // add the count to our message
    $MESSAGE = "Hey, motherlicker! You are visitor number $count!";
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <!-- metas -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Single page, protocol agnostic blank Bootstrap template.">
        <meta name="author" content="Rob Parham">
        <title>POOPS AND FARTS</title>

        <!-- styles -->
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body { padding-top: 70px; /* adjust for the navbar */ }
        </style>

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">POOP ON A STICK DOT COM</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- page content -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2>POOP DROPS</h2>
            <p><?php echo $MESSAGE; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- javascripts -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your time. It'd be great if you can give the PHP code of how getting the count and increment it.

Comment: @JustCurious - I'll hook you up with some code if you give me a upvote and a check :P

Comment: My reputation is under 15 so, I can't do the upvote. but I just did a check. :)

Comment: @JustCurious - Here's some code. You can click the check marrk by my name to select my answer. You said you did, but you didn';t. Hope this helps.

Comment: lol, I thought you said check on my profile.

Comment: and if the count was exist , how can i replace it to the new one ?

Comment: yiss, ty - That is included in the code that I provided. the line that says `fwrite($fh, $count);` does that

Comment: the fwrite in w+ mode as I know removes all the content that it was on the file before and add the new ones which in this case only count. I think I should use regex for that to replace it ?

Comment: @JustCurious - No, just try it the way I wrote it, it's fully functional if you copy the entire code into a php file and run it in your server you see how it works

Comment: is this count.txt file should only contains the number of how many visitors only ?

Comment: correct. you can put a json string in there if you need to save more info about each user of something, but at that point you might as well use a database.

Comment: i was thinking of a file like this name.txt that contains on each line an id=X where x is how many visitors on that special id

Comment: @JustCurious, easy enough, you'll wan tto look into json_encode() and json_decode() that way you can store entire objects and variables in the file.

Comment: It'd be great if you have time can tell me how to implement it using database. I'd really appreciate it :D

Comment: @JustCurious eh, what the hey. ok, I'll give you some database code when I get home from work. give me an hour or so.

Comment: hey it's been one day now and I still waiting for the database code.